# React Native: (assembleRelease) error: Invalid filename. Unable to add

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, react-native, gradlew

I'm having this error when trying to build the release apk with assembleRelease

> bundle: Done copying assets :app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processReleaseResources
>   /var/www/react-native-tc-demo/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/drawable-mdpi/src_screens_vuelos_screens_idavueltacontainer_screens_busqueda_components_trayecto_airlines_mairlines.png:
>   error: Invalid filename. Unable to add.
>
> :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

and this throws with --stacktrace

> Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution
>   failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'. at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
>   at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22) at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
>   at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
>   at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33) at
>   org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45) at
>   org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
>   at
>   org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23) at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
>   at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
>   at
>   org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:185)
>   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
>   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>   ... 60 more Caused by:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt at
>   com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:873)
>   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:178)
>   ... 68 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>   '/home/alejandro/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt' with arguments
>   {package -f --no-crunch -I
>   /home/alejandro/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar -M
>   /var/www/react-native-tc-demo/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml
>   -S /var/www/react-native-tc-demo/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release
>   -m -J /var/www/react-native-tc-demo/android/app/build/generated/source/r/release
>   -F /var/www/react-native-tc-demo/android/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-release.ap_
>   --custom-package com.demoturismocity -0 apk --output-text-symbols /var/www/react-native-tc-demo/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/release
>   --no-version-vectors} at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
>   at
>   com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:871)
>   ... 69 more Caused by:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>   '/home/alejandro/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt' with arguments
>   {package -f --no-crunch -I
>   /home/alejandro/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar -M
>   /var/www/react-native-tc-demo/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml
>   -S /var/www/react-native-tc-demo/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release
>   -m -J /var/www/react-native-tc-demo/android/app/build/generated/source/r/release
>   -F /var/www/react-native-tc-demo/android/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-release.ap_
>   --custom-package com.demoturismocity -0 apk --output-text-symbols /var/www/react-native-tc-demo/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/release
>   --no-version-vectors} at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:75)
>   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
>   at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
>   at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
>   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
>   at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
>   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:60)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/home/alejandro/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1 at
>   org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
>   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47)
>   ... 9 more
>
> BUILD FAILED

Reproduction

cd android &&./gradlew assembleRelease

Additional Information

I'm requiring a Component from
That file (MAirlines.png) is located in /src/screens/Vuelos/screens/Busqueda/component/Trayecto/airlines

- React Native version: 0.40.0
- Platform: Android
- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04
- Gradle version 2.2.3

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue. If you had run `cd android &&./gradlew assembleDebug` before, in order to test on the real device and bundled using `react-native bundle ...` it copies some asset files under `app/src/main/res/drawable-*`. Before going with `assembleRelease` you should better delete these folders.

Comment: I run assembleDebug and then assembleRelease and it worked (I also had to change getUseDeveloperSupport method from private to public then)
I guess some old debug files where causing the conflict.
Thank you

Comment: Glad if it helped a bit.

Answer (score 1):

During the `assembleRelease` React Native copies the images to android drawable folders with a new name composed by taking image's path, lowercasing it, replacing slashes with underscores, removing illegal characters and removing `assets_` prefix if present: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b0d68c0bb971a44dfdf7722682933f1e96e1cd45/local-cli/bundle/assetPathUtils.js#L63

```
function getAndroidResourceIdentifier(asset: PackagerAsset) {
  var folderPath = getBasePath(asset);
  return (folderPath + '/' + asset.name)
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\//g, '_') // Encode folder structure in file name
    .replace(/([^a-z0-9_])/g, '') // Remove illegal chars
    .replace(/^assets_/, ''); // Remove "assets_" prefix
}
```

For example: `src/components/MyComponent/components/SubComponent/images/myimage.png` becomes `src_components_mycomponent_components_subcomponent_images_myimage.png`

This issue appears when the resulting filename is too long. To be more specific, it happens when the resulting file name is longer than 100 characters: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36953084

There is also an open issue in React Native for this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16263

An workaround to this issue would be to move the images in a separate folder which is not nested so deep, resulting in a drawable file name not longer than 100 characters.

Comment: good solution to move the images to a seperate folder, has least impact on the project